# Put Magento 2 store in maintenance

Tags: magento2, maintenance

So I'm very new to Magento. I've the version 2.1.1 installed and I was wondering if someone could give me detailed step by step instructions to put my store in maintenance mode?

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways of maintenance as i know from my self.

1. [From Admin Panel](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html#instgde-cli-maint)
2. Redirect from your index.

First way is common:

> **Enable or disable maintenance mode**
>
> Magento uses maintenance mode to disable bootstrapping; for example,
>   while you’re maintaining, upgrading, or reconfiguring your site.
>
> Magento detects maintenance mode as follows:
>
> If var/.maintenance.flag does not exist, maintenance mode is off and
>   Magento operates normally. Otherwise, maintenance mode is on unless
>   var/.maintenance.ip exists:
>
> var/.maintenance.ip can contain a list of IP addresses. If an entry
>   point is accessed using HTTP and the client IP address corresponds to
>   one of the entries in that list, then maintenance mode is off.
>
> Command usage:
>
> magento maintenance:enable [--ip= ... --ip=] |
>   [ip=none] magento maintenance:disable [--ip= ... --ip=] | [ip=none] magento maintenance:status where
>
> --ip= is an IP address to exempt from maintenance mode (for example, developers doing the maintenance). To exempt more than
>   one IP address in the same command, use the option multiple times.
>
> Using **--ip=** with magento **maintenance:disable** means only
>   that you're saving the list of IPs for later use. To clear the list of
>   exempt IPs, you can use magento maintenance:enable --ip=none or see
>   Maintain the list of exempt IP addresses. magento maintenance:status
>   displays the current status of maintenance mode.
>
> For example, to enable maintenance mode with no IP address exemptions:
>
> **magento maintenance:enable To enable maintenance mode for all clients
>   except 192.0.2.10 and 192.0.2.11:**
>
> **magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.2.10 --ip=192.0.2.11**